# I wish to move desks at my company. How to word this request?

Tags: professionalism, office-layout

I am in the middle of a hustling, bustling office space where there is frequent noise and banter. While I enjoy the interpersonal communications to some extent, I have a difficult time sometimes focusing in on my work because I feel like I am constantly the center of attention.

How can I make a request to move to a quieter space without seeming nit-picky and petty?

Comment: Does your office have lounge areas? Why not grab your laptop and sit at one of those?

Answer (score 6):

It is perfectly reasonable to say this to your manager. Just ask! They might be able to solve it, and if not they will keep it in mind for the future (for example if a quieter spot opens up or if they redesign the office layout).

Comment: I did this.  I had a two person office with a guy who talked VERY loudly (e.g. one time someone walked over to our office, glared at him, and shut our door).  When a cubicle opened up nearby, I went straight to my boss and asked to move into it.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make a request to move to a quieter space without seeming
>   nit-picky and petty?

Don't "make a request". Instead, just talk to your boss face-to-face.

Something like "Hey boss, I think I could be a lot more productive if my desk was in a quieter spot. I'm think of [insert desired spot here]." should suffice.

Just talking and responding will come across as far less nit-picky and petty.